# Swift OOP: How to encapsulate Search behavior

Tags: swift, oop, search, encapsulation, object-oriented-analysis

Currently I have the following code:

```
import UIKit

struct ToBeSearched {
    var value1 = "1"
    var value2 = "3"
    var value3 = "3"
    var boolean = true
}

var data = [ToBeSearched]()
var completeData = [ToBeSearched]()

public func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    if let text = searchController.searchBar.text,
        !text.isEmpty {
        data = completeData.filter{
            // How to encapsulate this behavior, i.e. to extend it to use new values (value2, value2...)
            $0.value1.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased())
        }
    } else {
        data = completeData
    }
    reloadResults()
}
```

It's a simple search code that finds all the values where `value1` contain search text.

What if I'd like to match also `value2` and `value3`? How could I extract the search logic, so that it could be altered separately, without touching the main code.

Currently, I'd have to use the `binary OR` operator to go through all the cases:

```
let searchText = text.lowercased()
$0.value1.lowercased().contains(searchText) ||
$0.value2.lowercased().contains(searchText) ||
$0.value3.lowercased().contains(searchText)
...
```

Is there a more elegant way of achieving the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:  Specifiy the properties to search using `[KeyPath]`:**

If you just want to flexibly specify which fields to search of the `ToBeSearched` struct, you can pass in an array `[KeyPath]` of the properties to search, and use `contains` with a closure inside of `filter` to check if any of the properties identified by the keyPaths contain the text you are searching for:

```
public func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController, using keyPaths: [KeyPath<ToBeSearched, String>]) {
    if let text = searchController.searchBar.text,
        !text.isEmpty {
        data = completeData.filter { element in
            keyPaths.contains { keyPath in element[keyPath: keyPath].lowercased().contains(text.lowercased()) }
        }
    } else {
        data = completeData
    }
    reloadResults()
}
```

**Example:**

To search `value1` and `value2`:

```
updateSearchResults(for: searchController, using: [\.value1, \.value2])
```

---

**Method 2:  Pass in a closure for the `filter` method:**

```
public func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController, using filterProc: (ToBeSearched) -> Bool)  {
    if let text = searchController.searchBar.text,
        !text.isEmpty {
        data = completeData.filter(filterProc)
        }
    } else {
        data = completeData
    }
    reloadResults()
}
```

**Example:**

```
let filterProc: (ToBeSearched) -> Bool = {
    $0.value1.lowercased().contains(searchText) ||
    $0.value2.lowercased().contains(searchText)
}

updateSearchResults(for: searchController, using: filterProc)
```

Comment: Method 1 - a good balance between flexibility and verbosity 

Answer (score 0):

I hope this should solution what are you looking for. If structure is fixed, then you can implement following code, which is encapsulate comparison code inside structure.

```
struct ToBeSearched {
    var value1 = "1"
    var value2 = "3"
    var value3 = "3"
    var boolean = true

    func compareText(_ searchText: String) -> Bool {
        return value1.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) || value2.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) || value3.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
    }
}
```

This will compare all value without missing.

And update following line of code.

```
$0.compareText(text)
```

The main purpose is, you can check main objective method is added inside structure, so it can use anywhere instead to compare every single value inside `filter` method.

I hope this will help you.